# Why is System.Random giving '1' a lot of times in a row, then not for a while, then again?

Tags: c#, .net, random

Not sure how else to explain this, so the title pretty much describes the problem.

Random is not being re-initialised every part of the loop. It's a static member of a class which I always call on from other classes.

I am not using a custom seed.

The initialisation code is:

```
    public static Random random = new Random();

        for (int x = 0; x < 75; x++)
        {
            if (main.random.Next(11) == 1)
            {
                tiles[heightMap[x] - 1][x] = 4;
                tiles[heightMap[x] - 2][x] = 4;
                tiles[heightMap[x] - 3][x] = 4;
                tiles[heightMap[x] - 4][x] = 4;
                tiles[heightMap[x] - 5][x] = 4;
                tiles[heightMap[x] - 5][x - 1] = 5;
                tiles[heightMap[x] - 6][x - 1] = 5;
                tiles[heightMap[x] - 6][x] = 5;
                tiles[heightMap[x] - 5][x + 1] = 5;
                tiles[heightMap[x] - 6][x + 1] = 5;
            }
        }
```

This (I am aware this is not a great way - it's rudimentary and temporary) generates a tree.

However my terrain often looks something like this, with many clustered trees:

☁☁☁☁☁☁☁☁☁☁

Can anyone give insight into why this is happening? Is there a better alternative than using the System.Security.Cryptography.Random class?

I'd expect an average of 9 gap per tree, but it's more like 7 and then 3 trees closely clustered together.

[image]

Comment: http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2001-10-25/

Comment: Random doesn't mean frequent changes in alternative outcomes. Over time, the sequence like this is uniformly distributed.

Comment: If you are truly getting a non-random distribution, you can try normalizing the values to correct for it.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is a probability misunderstanding; all you know is that **at any point**, the chance of getting a tree in the next slot is, assuming uniform distribution, 1 in 11.

The chance of getting a gap of 0 is thus 1/11

The chance of getting a gap of 1 is thus 10/11 * 1/11

The chance of getting a gap of 2 is thus 10/11 * 10/11 * 1/11

etc

All those 10/11 add (well, *multiply*) up! So let's write a utility:

```
decimal accountedFor = 0M;
for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
{
    decimal chance = 1M / 11M;
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) chance *= 10M / 11M;
    accountedFor += chance;
    Console.WriteLine("{0:00}: {1:00.0%}\t({2:00.0%})", i, chance, accountedFor);
}
```

Which gives:

```
00: 09.1%       (09.1%)
01: 08.3%       (17.4%)
02: 07.5%       (24.9%)
03: 06.8%       (31.7%)
04: 06.2%       (37.9%)
05: 05.6%       (43.6%)
06: 05.1%       (48.7%)
07: 04.7%       (53.3%)
08: 04.2%       (57.6%)
09: 03.9%       (61.4%)
10: 03.5%       (65.0%)
11: 03.2%       (68.1%)
12: 02.9%       (71.0%)
13: 02.6%       (73.7%)
14: 02.4%       (76.1%)
15: 02.2%       (78.2%)
16: 02.0%       (80.2%)
17: 01.8%       (82.0%)
18: 01.6%       (83.6%)
19: 01.5%       (85.1%)
20: 01.4%       (86.5%)
```

which explains the bias for small gaps. Note; by the time we get up to a gap of size 20, we're into below 1.5% chance territory, and have accounted for 85% of all possible outcomes - the remaining 15% will be spread over the rest of infinity (i.e. a gap of size 13212 is possible, but very unlikely).

So here's a simulation:

```
int[] gapCounts = new int[21];

int gap = 0;
// simulate a few gaps using your algo
var random = new Random();
for (int x = 0; x < 100000; x++)
{
    if (random.Next(11) == 1)
    { // count that gap
        gapCounts[gap]++;
        gap = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        gap++;
        if(gap >= gapCounts.Length)
        { // just skip anything too large, sorry
            gap = 0;
        }
    }
}

decimal total = gapCounts.Sum();
for(int i = 0 ; i < gapCounts.Length ; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0:00}: {1:00.0%}", i, gapCounts[i] / total);
}
```

with output **nothing that these values will change every run**:

```
00: 11.0%
01: 09.4%
02: 08.6%
03: 07.9%
04: 07.3%
05: 06.5%
06: 05.4%
07: 05.4%
08: 04.7%
09: 04.5%
10: 04.4%
11: 03.4%
12: 03.5%
13: 03.0%
14: 02.9%
15: 02.4%
16: 02.5%
17: 02.2%
18: 01.9%
19: 01.5%
20: 01.7%
```

Comment: Yes, show the running cumulative version of the above, it'll be enlightening.

Comment: But it seems to lean a lot towards 1 and 7, whereas numbers such as 2 are very rarely picked (In a string of 75 numbers, 2 was picked only four times, and I'm getting this sort of result a lot). It also seems very common to get three 7s in a row, and then not any 7s for a very long time. This isn't just on one run, I'm getting lots of similar patterns like that triple 7 and rare 2 occurrences. From a mathematical point of view I can see where you're coming from, but I just think it's the .NET System.Random class not having a good enough algorithm.

Comment: And another run just gave me "3,2,3,7,3,2,3,7,3,3,7" Surely there's something wrong there? (Also in the same run was "2,3,4,4,5,5,0,1")

Comment: @AshleyDavies see, now there you *do* get into the realm of the Dilbert cartoon - you never can be sure! Let me try something, though...

Comment: @AshleyDavies I added a simulation using your algorithm; data looks about right to me (i.e. roughly consistent with the prediction)

Comment: It does make a lot more sense with your results. I'm still getting odd occurrences like gaps of 42 (Which I'm tempted to believe is a hard-coded easter egg), but the trees make more sense. I'll probably have to force it to make sure all gaps are 3 or above. Thanks for helping, and being so thorough in your answer!

Comment: @AshleyDavies, The framework's algorithm is well known and passes many statistical tests for random numbers. Is it cryptography strength? No. But there's nothing wrong with it randomness wise.